# Turn on Flash and Front camera at the same time on iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, camera, flashlight, front-camera

I need to use the Front camera and have the back light LED turned on in iPhone.
how can I do that?
I can open the front camera using this code:

```
- (void) turnCameraOn {
if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {

    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePicker.delegate = self;
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    imagePicker.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront;
    imagePicker.cameraCaptureMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModePhoto;
    imagePicker.showsCameraControls = YES;

    [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];

} else {

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Camera unavaliable"
                                                    message:@"Unable to find camera on your device."
                                                   delegate:nil
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
    alert = nil;
}
}
```

and I can turn the led on with this code

```
- (void) turnTorchOn: (bool) on {
Class captureDeviceClass = NSClassFromString(@"AVCaptureDevice");
if (captureDeviceClass != nil) {
    AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    if ([device hasTorch] && [device hasFlash]){

        [device lockForConfiguration:nil];

        if (on) {
            [device setTorchMode:AVCaptureTorchModeOn];
            [device setFlashMode:AVCaptureFlashModeOn];
        } else {
            [device setTorchMode:AVCaptureTorchModeOff];
            [device setFlashMode:AVCaptureFlashModeOff];
        }
        [device unlockForConfiguration];
    }
}
}
```

But when I open the APP and the front camera appear the led turns off.
I need both working at the same time.

Thanks

Comment: Any luck so far for this?

Comment: nothing :( Looks like apple can do that. Because if you realize the apple flashlight don´t access camera like all others flashlight app.

Comment: @rendellhb:I want this same functionality in android.Do you know if thats possible ?

Answer (score 0):

This is not permitted on iOS with current set of APIs.
You can understand this by apple's own camera app.

Even they also turn OFF torch when you toggle to use front camera, and do not show the torch switch in that mode.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIImagePickerController/isFlashAvailableForCameraDevice:) check out `isFlashAvailableForCameraDevice` property of UIImagePickerController to check if the flash is allowed with `UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront` property.